# Can I add node_modules and bower_components to .gitignore when I use Yeoman?

Tags: npm, yeoman, bower

I'm using Yeoman to generate an angular app. I can see it's made a `bower.json` file and a `package.json` file. Does that mean I can add `node_modules` and `bower_components` to `.gitignore`? If I do, how do I get npm and bower to reinstall all the components when I check it out again?

Comment: I was looking for an answer to this same question and came across [this post](http://addyosmani.com/blog/checking-in-front-end-dependencies/) on Addy Osmani's blog covering the topic. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `postinstall` script to your `package.json` file.

Postinstall will automatically run after install.

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "start": "node server.js"
},
```